# Parse.com javascript update query - "record is not defined"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am experiencing a strange bug in which my update query works only when I explicitly write out a record's ID (otherwise, I get a `record is not defined` error in my browser's console if I try to store the ID in a variable). Here's an example.

This one works:

```
var Point = Parse.Object.extend("pizza");
var point = new Point();
point.id = "aB3ErRa1"; 
var email = "you@yourself.com";
point.set("useremail", email);
```

This one does not:

```
var Point = Parse.Object.extend("pizza");
var point = new Point();
point.id = record.id;
console.log(point.id); //prints out the correct ID as a string
var email = "you@yourself.com";
point.set("useremail", email);
```

Any ideas? Is this the best way to execute an update?

Comment: sorry for the messy formatting, did not come out as expected

Comment: what happens when you invoke 'typeof record.id' ? is it really a string?

Comment: @Shai thanks that was a useful test, turns out it is really a string. any ideas?

Comment: just for the sake of it - try changing 'point.id = record.id' to 'point.id = "" + record.id', see how it goes